# jQuery Dialog Always Opening Top Left

Tags: jquery

I am trying to align the dialog next to the button but every time the dialog appears in the top left.

Can anyone take a look at this jsFiddle and tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
<http://jsfiddle.net/QFp2J/68/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [jQueryUI Position](http://jqueryui.com/position/)

```
    $("#divDialog").dialog({
        height: 350,
        width: 450,
        modal: false,
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        position: { my: "left top", at: "right top", of: $("#btnOpen") }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QFp2J/69/